# Button content going outside of button when resizing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have this button and I put some text in it using Content="1", there's a 15px padding around the top and 20px on the left side of the number, however the text appears to go outside of the button when it is resized.

this is what it normally is
[image: number1]

and this is what happens when it resizes
[image: number2]

if it helps any, here is the XAML code:

`<Button x:Name="_btn1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="214" FontSize="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Height="182" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#33999999" Click="DayClick" Padding="20,15,0,0"/>`

Comment: whats your container's size? is it larger or smaller than the button? im suspecting its getting cut off due to parent size

Comment: I'm not really sure, how would I check that?

Comment: you can check it using the live inspection tool

Answer (score 1):

Your content is not going outside; some portion of the button is hiding behind the content holder like `StackPanel`, `Grid` or whatever you are using.

**Here are something you can do -**

1. Use button's auto size instead of hard code size.

   ```
   <Button x:Name="_btn1" 
           Content="1" 
           FontSize="24"
           Background="SeaGreen"
           Margin="10,10,10,10" 
           Grid.Row="1" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   ```
2. Use `ScrollViwer` outside of your container.

   ```
   <ScrollViewer>
       <StackPanel>
           <Button x:Name="_btn1" 
                   Content="1" 
                   FontSize="24"
                   Background="SeaGreen" 
                   Width="214"   
                   Height="182"
                   Padding="20,15,0,0"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
   ```

> You can't use `ScrollViwer` inside of a `StackPanel`

3. Use `AdaptiveTrigger` and change the buttons' properties as you need.

(Read the doc if you are not familiar - [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger))